# different between executable location

Tags: c#, directory, location

if I want to get executable location
what is the different between this command:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

is there any different ? 
is its pointed to different location ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Gets the location of the executing assembly. In an ASP.NET application this could vary due to shadow copying assemblies in system folders. The location of the currently executing assembly could be different than the location of the hosting process.

> Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Gets the current working directory of the hosting process. In most cases this will be the directory where the executable is located but this working directory could be modified programatically using the [SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) method.

> System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;

The directory from which the hosting process was started.

---

In a desktop application where you have everything in the same folder the 3 might return the same.

Comment: "would probably return the same" is wrong, you can never rely on that. Working directory ("current dir") can be set in shortcut properties, or you can run the program from a different directory from a command line.

Comment: @matejcik, that's why I said `would` and not `will always`. I should have used a different word though: `might`.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` returns a folder of specified assembly.
2. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` *gets* the *system current* directory **without** backslash, according to MSDN. [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx)
3. `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` *gets* or *sets* system current directory.

Answer (score 2):

The current directory is the working directory, it's not necessarily the same as the directory that contains your assembly.

For example, if you were on the command line, in the root C:\ drive and did the command "SomeFolder\MyProgram.exe" the current directory would still be C:\